# Implement repositories in application root instead of dependency injections

Tags: android, dependency-injection, android-viewmodel

I found an [Android Compose Repository pattern sample](https://www.raywenderlich.com/24509368-repository-pattern-with-jetpack-compose) that uses the application class as a storage of repositories. Is it a good solution to use instead of a dependency injection framework (like `Koin`)?

```
class WordsApp : Application() {
  private val database by lazy {
    Room.databaseBuilder(this, AppDatabase::class.java, "database.db").build()
  }

  val wordRepository by lazy { WordRepository(database) }
}

class MainViewModel(application: Application) : AndroidViewModel(application) {
  private val wordRepository = getApplication<WordsApp>().wordRepository
```

Comment: `Is it a good solution to use instead of a dependency injection` how is this an alternative to dependency injection ?

Comment: You don't need to use DI there because you implemented everything manually.

Comment: i don't agree with your understanding of DI. dependency injection is essentially helping to manage and get dependencies where they need to be. the fact that you put it in the application class doesn't help with that, what if i have a repository that requires 3 other _dependencies_, then i could still use DI for that, i could quite happily use DI in my application class and everywhere else too

Comment: Yes, it looks like minor dependencies is hard to maintain here.